# Electron needs page reload to show content

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, electron

I'm new to [Electron](https://electron.atom.io), my goal is to run a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) app within. The Django app has been compiled using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) and placed correctly within my electron project structure.

My problem is that when I start electron (`electron .`) its blank window opens. I need to hit refresh to show to right content. I cannot get this to work such that the page is reloaded to show content during electron opening. I tried the `reload()` and `reloadIgnoringCache()` option but it doesn't help...

Analysing my window `webContents` parameters I can see that my window initially gets `currentIndex: -1` and after manually reloading `currentIndex: 0` (not sure if that is relevant...).

Here is the relevant part of my `main.js` file:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
log.info('App is ready?!....');

var openWindow = function(mainAddr){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 800, backgroundColor: '#eeeeee', show:false});
    mainWindow.loadURL(mainAddr);
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
        mainWindow.show();

    });
    mainWindow.webContents.session.clearCache(function() {
        console.log("Cache has been cleared.");
    });
    mainWindow.webContents.reloadIgnoringCache();
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
        subpy.kill('SIGINT');
    });


};
```

Comment: hi , have you tried 'ready-to-show' event?

Comment: hi @AnatolyStrashkevich - thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try and it turns out the window doesn't open at all... So I can't even hit the refresh button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - it turned out that the problem is linked to the way how my django server is starting... It needs few seconds to get started, which is when Electron was trying to reach it with no success - hence the white screen.

After the introduction of timeout timer, like this:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('waiting ....');
                mainWindow.loadURL(mainAddr);
    },4000);
```

the problem was 'gone' after waiting those 4 seconds ...

Comment: Are you sure it will always be 4 seconds to start server? maybe better idea will be to setup socket connection with server and setup callback on server load?